# How to open a form in upward direction on hover or on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to create a button(on bottom right) which will open a form after clicking or hovering on it. The form will slide(slowly) open and close after clicking on login, my code is making the button going down as the form is opening.

Also the button should be on the right side, I've tried `float:right;` and `right:0;` to fix the button to right but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```js
function showForm(){
  document.getElementById('loginForm').style.display = "block";
}

function hideForm(){
  document.getElementById('loginForm').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
   .no-show{display:none;}
   .form-container {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  float: right;
  width:100%;
}
body { font-family: tahoma; }
#loginForm  {
 display: none;
 background: #ccc;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 20px;
 color: #333;
}
.label {
   cursor: pointer;
   display:block;
   padding: 5px 15px;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;    
}
.form-label {
 width: 70px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.form-field {
 width: 180px;
}

.form-elements {
 font-size: 0px;
 margin: 10px 0 0 0;
 display: block;
}

.form-label, .form-field {
 display: inline-block;
}

.form-field input {
 padding: 3px 5px;
}

.submit-btn input {
 margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-container">
<form>
  <p id="login" onmouseover="showForm();" onmouseout="hideForm();">
 <span class="label">Login</span>  
 <span id="loginForm">        
   <span class="form-elements">
    <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
    <span class="form-field"><input type="name" /></span>
  </span>        
   <span class="form-elements">
    <span class="form-label">Password:</span>
    <span class="form-field"><input type="password" /></span>
  </span>
 </span>      
  </p>
</form>
</div>
```

Here's the working fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/d5L8bywk/1/

Form should open(up side) slowly with ease and should close after click on login button.

It should look like this: [image: Like this]

Comment: @calvin-nunes Thank you for the edit! Should js always be the first?

Comment: Please, I couldn't understand the exact desired behavior. Should the "OpenForm" button disappear after click? should the form appear below the button? Should entire form be inside the blue area?

Comment: You mean, for a snippet? No, it is pre-defined by the SO, use the `<>` button that is in the toolbar when [edit]ing and you'll see that there some "squares" to place each part of your code

Comment: The form should open above the button "open form". Yes, after click it should disappear. The form shouldn't have to be inside the blue area.

Comment: By absolute positioning the form, you will be pushing it down instead of sliding it up. One option for anyone wanting to try is using jquery animate to change the "bottom" value instead of using slide.

Comment: I used absolute positioning because I wanted form div i.e form-container to stick at the bottom. Without this it's displaying at the top.

Comment: @calvin-nunes Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @nonliving So you need to hide the button after clicking it?

Comment: @ΑntonisPapadakis Yes, it should hide. After submitting the form and form closes then button should appear

Comment: @CalvinNunes I've edited the question to make it more clear, please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code. No jQuery needed, you can achieve this with pure css transition in combination with height property.

```js
function showForm() {
  document.getElementById('loginForm').classList.add('show');
}

function hideForm() {
  document.getElementById('loginForm').classList.remove('show');
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: tahoma;
  height: 100vh;
}

.no-show{
  display:none;
}

.form-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 80px;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  width: 230px;
}

#loginForm  {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 250px;
  color: #333;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#loginForm.show {
  height: 150px;
}

.label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display:block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.form-label {
  width: 70px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.form-field {
  width: 180px;
}

.form-elements {
  font-size: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-label, .form-field {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.form-field input {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.submit-btn input {
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#login {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="form-container">
<form>
    <div id="loginForm" onmouseleave="hideForm();">
      <span class="form-elements">
        <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
        <span class="form-field"><input type="name" /></span>
      </span>
      <span class="form-elements">
        <span class="form-label">Password:</span>
        <span class="form-field"><input type="password" /></span>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>

<span id="login" class="label" onmouseover="showForm();">Login</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's good, button is hidden now. Only thing is that the form is opening downwards, I want it to open upward direction so the "open form" button don't move it's position

Comment: Can you please point out what is wrong with the code? It's make me crazy please!

Comment: Updated, please check

Comment: This is working perfectly! Is there a way to make login button as a submit button for the form too or should I use other button for it?

Comment: You can put an <input type="submit"> inside the form

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
#login{
float:right 
}

<div class="form-container">
  <form>
<p id="login" onmouseover="showForm();" onmouseout="hideForm()">

  <span id="loginForm">        
      <span class="form-elements">
        <span class="form-label">Name:</span>
        <span class="form-field"><input type="name"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="form-elements">
        <span class="form-label">Password:</span>
        <span class="form-field"><input type="password"></span>
      </span>
  </span>
   <span class="label">Login</span></p>
 </form>
</div>
```